# Protobuf алиасы в golang

Tags: golang, google-protobuf

Есть большое количество структур вида:

```
type TypeId1 int64
type TypeId2 int64
type MyStruct struct {
    Id1 TypeId1
    Id2 TypeId2
}
```

Данные из этих структур нужно схоранять в хранилище. Узким местом является сериализация и десереализация, которая требуется, например, для складирования данных в БД или редис.

Одиним из стандартов для решения такой задачи является protobuf. Подскажите, как сложить всё это в protobuf? Хотелось бы сохранить алиасы, так как они полезны для избежания путаницы id при обращении по ключу. Например, при написании кода часто встречаются ошибки вида. Например, при написании кода часто встречаются ошибки вида:

```
id1ToValue := map[int64]int64{}
id2ToValue := map[int64]int64{}

id1 := int64(1)
id2 := int64(1)

id1ToValue[id2] = 1
id2ToValue[id1] = 1
```

Доступ по id оказывается ошибочным. При этом, возможна компиляция. Если же вместо ключей `int64` использовать `TypeId1` и `TypeId2`, то компиляция будет невозможной:

```
id1ToValue := map[TypeId1]int64{}
id2ToValue := map[TypeId2]int64{}

id1 := TypeId1(1)
id2 := TypeId2(1)

id1ToValue[id2] = 1
id2ToValue[id1] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас опасная путаница в терминологии. Вот это:

```golang
type TypeID1 int64
```

*определение типа* ([«type definition»](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), он же «[newtype](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype)» у любителей хаскела), а синоним (он же [«type alias»](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations)) — это вот:

```golang
type TypeID1 = int64
```

Что же касается основного вопроса, нигде в документации Протобуфа не нахожу ни определений, ни синонимов. Наоборот, [пишут](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/protobuf/uvcQc43-_r0/aVdi1uI6lI0J), что нету. Так что лучшее, что вы можете сделать, это такая неловкая конструкция:

```protobuf
message TypeId1 {
    int64 value = 1;
}
```

Comment: Да, в протобуфе мы ничего в доке тоже не нашли по этому поводу. Что делать с конструкцией, которую Вы предложили?

Comment: Использовать в протобуфе, чтобы различать типы. Это техника, взятая из си.